# React Redux state not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

please help me with a situation around react-redux.
I have issues in updating the state ( which i try to do in a immutable way ), and the component where I use it, never rerenders.

/store/users/index.js

```
import { USER_LOGIN, USER_LOGOUT} from './actionTypes';

import {
    USER_LOGIN,
    USER_LOGOUT
} from './actionTypes';

const usersReducer = (user = {}, action) => {
    switch(action) {
        case USER_LOGIN : /* tried to change id manually, not based on payload, just to see if it works */
            return {
                ...user, 
                name: 'New user',
                isLoggedIn: true
            }
        case USER_LOGOUT: 
            return {
                ...user,
                name: 'Anonymous',
                isLoggedIn: false
            }
        default:
            return user;
    }  
}
export default usersReducer;
```

/store/loops/index.js

```
import {
    LOOPS_ADD
} from './actionTypes';
const loopsReducer = (loops =[], action) => {
    switch(action) {
        case LOOPS_ADD:
            return [
                ...loops,
                action.payload
            ]
        default:
            return loops;
    }
}
export default loopsReducer;
```

/store/users/actions.js

```
import {
    USER_LOGIN,
    USER_LOGOUT
}
from './actionTypes';

export const userLogin = (newUser) => {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGIN,
    }
}

export const userLogout = () => {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGOUT
    }
}
```

/store/index.js

```
import {
    createStore, 
    combineReducers, 
    applyMiddleware, 
    compose
} from 'redux';
/* import reducers */
import usersReducer from './users';
import loopsReducer from './loops';

/* import middleware */
import logger from 'redux-logger';

/* initial state */
const initialState =  {
    user: {
        name: 'Anonymous',
        isLoggedIn: false,
        email: null,
        lastLogin: null,
        firstTimeLogin: false,
        authProvider: 'email',
        friendsCount: null
    },
    loops: []
}

/* reducers */
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: usersReducer,
    loops: loopsReducer,
});

/* store creation */
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const middleware = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(logger));

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    middleware
);

export default store;
```

/pages/HomeScreen/HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {userLogin} from '../../store/users/actions';

class Home extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <NavBar>Nav</NavBar>
                <Listing>
                    <Filter>Filter</Filter>
                    <Card>
                        <CardAvatar>Avatar</CardAvatar>
                        <CardBody>Rest of the card</CardBody>
                        Salut {this.props.name}
                        <button onClick={() => this.props.login()}>login</button>
                    </Card>
                </Listing>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps  = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.user.name
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        login: () => dispatch(userLogin()),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

I don't know if it matters but i'm using styled-components for styling. 
I tried removing the `combineReducers` method, and remain with a single reducer, that did not help.

I tried removing the `react-logger` middleware, I tried using `Immutable.js`but even if the actions is triggered the redux state does not update, and the Home component doesn't rerender as well.

Comment: didn't work won't help, you need to specify what you want

Comment: sorry. i've updated the above code as well. The problem is that the state does not update after the actions is triggered .

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You should really try to narrow your problem down. First of all it will help you to find the origin of the problem, and last but not least, it won't discourage people from trying to help you because the amount of code to digest is so huge.

Comment: Thank you for being so understanding with new people.

Comment: could you specify which one to reduce the inconvenience? or does no reducer work?

Comment: I tried firing actions for both reducers and none of them update the state. 
So to summarise : 
- the initial state is set ( i can access it, and can render it )
- the actions are fired ( i see in the redux devtools )
- the state doesn't change after action fires, event tho the reducers should handle it ( based on the code above)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not setting the `user` on your action:

```
export const userLogin = (newUser) => {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGIN,
    }
}
```

Looks like it needs to be:

```
export const userLogin = (newUser) => {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGIN,
        user: newUser
    }
}
```

Without this there will be no change in state and also no render needed.

Of course, you would then need to change your reducer function so that it is dynamic:

```
case USER_LOGIN : 
    return {
        ...user, 
        name: action.user.name,
        isLoggedIn: true
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried like that, but it did not update, so i tried to just updated it with static information in the reducer 
`case USER_LOGIN : /* tried to change id manually, not based on payload, just to see if it works */
            return {
                ...user, 
                name: 'New user',
                isLoggedIn: true
            }
`

Comment: I tried like this: 
`<button onClick={() => this.props.login({ name: 'Logged in user' })}>login</button>`

`    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            login: (user) => dispatch(userLogin(user)),
        }
    }
`
`export const userLogin = (loggedInUser) => {
        return {
            type: USER_LOGIN,
            payload: loggedInUser
        }
    }
` 
in the reducer:
`case USER_LOGIN :
            return {
                ...user,
                name: action.payload.name,
                isLoggedIn: true
            }
`but no change

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.
I was doing :

```
const loopsReducer = (loops =[], action) => {
    switch(action) {
        case LOOPS_ADD:
            return [
                ...loops,
                action.payload
            ]
        default:
            return loops;
    }
}
```

instead i should have done

```
const loopsReducer = (loops =[], action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOOPS_ADD:
            return [
                ...loops,
                action.payload
            ]
        default:
            return loops;
    }
}
```

Notice the switch(action) before to **switch(action.type)**
Sorry for wasting your time, and thank you for all your replies !